# Is radiation emitted in a particular direction by a body?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

If a body is transferring heat by the mode of radiation, then will it emit it at direction perpendicular to its surface only, or will it be emitted in all the directions.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law

Answer (score 0):

If the radiation is unpolarized, it will be emitted in random directions, but within a probabilistic distribution. If it is polarized then it will be emitted in a single direction

Comment: So will the radiations emitted by the sun normal to its surface?